# Use PHP to create XML file from SQL table data

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have this table...

```
rss(
    id serial,
    title varchar(25) not null,
    link text not null,
    description TEXT not null,
    imagename text
);
```

... i am trying to create an xml file from the data stored using php.

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "s3382313");
$q = 'select * from rss';
$run = mysqli_query($db, $q);

if( $run && mysqli_num_rows( $run ) ) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument( '1.0' );
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

    $root = $doc->createElement( 'data' );
    $doc->appendChild( $root );

    while( ( $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $run ) )!== false ) {
        $node = $doc->createElement( 'node' );
        $root->appendChild( $node );

        foreach( $fetch as $key => $value ) {
            createNodes( $key, $value, $doc, $node );
        }
    }
    $doc->save("thexmlfile.xml");
}

function createNodes( $key, $value, $doc, $node ) {
    $key = $doc->createElement( $key );
    $node->appendChild( $key );
    $key->appendChild( $doc->createTextNode( $value ) );
}
```

I am receiving this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeatherRadar\process_XML.php on line 27

line 27 is :`foreach( $fetch as $key => $value ) {`

what do i do?

Comment: You should check the variable $fetch. What print_r($fetch); is outputing?

Comment: Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => test rss [link] => test.link [description] => test description [imagename] => IMG_1667.jpg )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `$fetch` is scoped within one too many brackets, it's currently solely testing the validity for the while condition.

```
while((true != false)) { 
    //...
}
```

Thus, rewrite too:

```
while( $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $run )) {
   /** $fetch will be scoped for the loop now **/
}
```

Secondly for debugging, important to check the contents of `$fetch` prior to iterating it, as it may not be a nested result set.

Comment: with the above code that i posted the $fetch output is 'Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => test rss [link] => test.link [description] => test description [imagename] => IMG_1667.jpg ) '

Comment: with your line the $fetch output is '1' still with the same error

Comment: @EJackson remove the `!== false` as the while will stop once the `$run` iterated to the end anyway.